# Site included in the Google News but the indexed articles are only shown in Sorted by Date in News Section, Why?

Tags: google-search, google-news

We have recently switched from http to https, we have set our new webmaster tools and sitemap. Google team has set ournew settings for our domain in their side and confirmed it is included in the News too.
By seraching site:domain.com everything is Ok, but when we search the title of articles we can see them in Search, when we go to New section they are not shown in Sorted by Relevance and we have to change the sort to Sorted by Date to see the articles.
I am confused and the Google Support team told me to get help in the forums.
Please let me know and help 
Regards

P.S. This issue for about a week and 3 days ago it came Ok without any changes in our side and again the issue has come back.